# ElasticSearch multiple fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

I'm beginner in elasticsearch and I have no idea to solve my problem.
Here is my problem:

```
{"email"=>"fritz.lilla.ritchie@example.net",
"full_name"=>"Lilla Fritz Ritchie",
"location"=>"Connecticut",
"postition"=>"Developer",
"about"=>
 "Atque nihil dolorum et quod ea aut debitis. Aliquid commodi eos et architecto nostrum. Rerum aut sunt sed molestiae consequatur. Ut ut est id voluptatem maiores. Sed voluptate aut consequatur asperiores reprehenderit iure optio.",
"skills"=>
 [{"name"=>"SQLServer", "year_experience"=>2},
  {"name"=>"MySQL", "year_experience"=>6},
  {"name"=>"Aps.net", "year_experience"=>7},
  {"name"=>"Ruby on Rails", "year_experience"=>8},
  {"name"=>"PHP", "year_experience"=>4},
  {"name"=>"Amazon EC2", "year_experience"=>4}],
"id"=>3}
```

This is User document in ES, I need find anyone with skills and year experience corresponding. 
Example : my input is Ruby on Rails 8 years experience and Amazon EC2 skills with 5 years experience.

=> Expect result :

- have Ruby on rails skill and order by year experience
- have Amazon EC2 skill and order by year experience.

Anyone help me how I can write ES query for that case. Sorry about my bad english.

Comment: i assume you are looking for both the skills "my input is Ruby on Rails 8 years experience and Amazon EC2 skills with 5 years experience."

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I understood your mapping. I hope the following query answers your question.

```
  {
        "query": {
             "filtered": {
                    "filter": 
                        "bool": {
                           "term": {
                               "skills.name": "Ruby"
                           }
                        }
                    }
             }
        },
        "sort": {
             "skills.year_experience": {
                    "order": "asc"
             }
        }
  }
```

You can also  change `asc` to `desc` if the sorting is not in the right order.

Answer (score 0):

i took a look at your json document and i suggest you to first enforce [nested](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) data type for skills data type.

Also in the mappings since by default is standard analyzer which will break your input on whitespace i.e "Ruby on Rails" will result in "ruby", "on", "rails" and the [standard](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) analyzer won't retain the actual field in the inverted index unless you create a custom analyzer to lowercase the keyword or use [multi-fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html) in mappings to support search for other usecases.

Here i have provided minimum mappings and settings for your current usecase to work and you can extend this to support other use cases.

I also suggest you to take a look at [nested](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html) queries for elastic.

**Mappings**

```
PUT index_playtime1
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "lowercase_keyword": {
                    "tokenizer": "keyword",
                    "filter": ["lowercase"]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "document_type": {
            "properties": {
                "skills": {
                    "type": "nested",
                    "properties": {
                        "name": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "analyzer": "lowercase_keyword"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Query**

```
POST index_playtime1/document_type/_search


   {
    "sort": {
        "skills.year_experience": {
            "order": "asc"
        }
    },
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [{
                    "nested": {
                        "path": "skills",
                        "query": {
                            "bool": {
                                "must": [{
                                    "bool": {
                                        "must": [{
                                                "term": {
                                                    "skills.name": {
                                                        "value": "ruby on rails"
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "term": {
                                                    "skills.year_experience": {
                                                        "value": 8
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "nested": {
                        "path": "skills",
                        "query": {
                            "bool": {
                                "must": [{
                                    "bool": {
                                        "must": [{
                                                "term": {
                                                    "skills.name": {
                                                        "value": "amazon ec2"
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "term": {
                                                    "skills.year_experience": {
                                                        "value": 4
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

let know in case this doesn't suite your usecase.